# MMO Data Structure: Array vs. Object Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, relational-database

Imagine Agar.io. At any one time, there'll be lots of food, player cells and viruses. Every update tick, you'll need to update every single player with every single object within that player's field of view.

I am using Node with Socket.IO and am not sure whether to use arrays to store my data (ie players, cells, food and viruses) or a relational array (object) (ie each game object has its own key in a master object for fast access).

I did [this performance test](http://v.ht/JavaScriptArrayVsObjectsMMOPeformance), and with lots of game objects, using a relational array (object) is much, much faster.

Is this the best way to go?

Comment: I guess you best change your last line to `console.log("Object: "+o[odn]+" after "+(Date.now()-at));`

Comment: @Redu I don't really understand what you mean. What I'm saying is that objects allow you to access fields in less than 1 millisecond.